# Why was my question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I was trying to customize the boot splash screen on a live USB stick, and I was having problems, so I decided to [ask](https://askubuntu.com/q/246897/95681) about it. My question was specifically about how to customize the splash screen on a Live USB drive (and I was fairly clear on that point.)

Unfortunately, it was closed as being an "exact duplicate" of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/173329/95681), which is a question about desktop installations, with answers that are only applicable to desktop installations. It does not address, or even touch on live medias. Why, then was my question closed as a duplicate?

Could it be reopened? What would it take to get it reopened?

Comment: The question has been reopened by Oli.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is closed because the title is generic, you can always go back and add more detail (in the question, not the comments) so it doesn't seem like a duplicate, I went ahead and made the edits into the question and voted to reopen.

Comment: -1 The question had plenty of detail, why didn't you just fix the title in the first place?

Comment: @Seth I had no idea that the title was the issue. I didn't think that someone who had made it all the way to three thousand reputation would cast a close vote without even reading the question. :(

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I was talking to Jorge (that's why I put the comment under _his_ post).

Comment: We get dozens of duplicate questions a day, so if the most important part of the question (the title) is generic chances are people reviewing it are more likely to close it. The solution is easy, if it's too generic, fix it and it'll get reopened; afaict that's what we did here.